# Django templates: tags in tags

Tags: django, templates, tags

In Django templates, I am trying to have a tag within another tag:

The project's `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^lists/', include('lists.urls', namespace='lists')),
```

The `lists` app's `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^new/$', views.newList, name='newList'),
url(r'^(?P<listID>[0-9]+)/$', views.viewList, name='viewList'),
```

base.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% {% block url %}{% endblock %} %}">
 ...
</form>
```

home.html:

```
{% block url %} url 'lists:newList' {% endblock %}
```

list.html:

```
{% block url %} url 'lists:viewList' {{list.id}} {% endblock %}
```

It doesn't seem to work.
The result of home.html is

```
<form method="POST" action=" url 'lists:newList' ">
```

instead of what I want:

```
<form method="POST" action="/lists/new/">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

base.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% block url %}{% endblock %}">
 ...
</form>
```

home.html

```
{% block url %} {% url 'lists:newList' %} {% endblock %}
```